# Tortoise SVN: Merging a file from an "API" directory into multiple project directories

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have have the following repo structure:

```
 /root
 ----/API
 ---------ReusableClass1.vb
 ----/MyProject
 ---------/source
 -------------SomeFile.vb
 -------------ReusableClass1.vb (to update with revisions to above ReusableClass1.vb)
```

Question:
How can I create some sort of`ReusableClass1.vb` branch that lives in the API branch (the true owner of the file) but also keep a copy of it in MyProject directory? I would like to "pull" the updates to the MyProjct source directory periodically, but the revisions to be always up to date in the `/API` directory?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SVN externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html), because you have common repository for externals source and target - it can be file-type externals (and if your SVN is at least 1.6)

Comment: would you mind taking a look at my next question:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/32723369/1751090 ? I can't seem to get the right file url or local path syntax. Thank you.